# how Consistent is two Shared Object(.so) file which have same code

Tags: c++, c, dll, shared-libraries

Is there any consistency when generating a .so file between two builds? When we perform clean and build?

Basically, I wanted the .so file for an app for a previous state of the code (C++), the files changed were very few, which i reverted back, if i build now will the so file be same as the one i got before?

I can replicate the code state to exactly what it was before, I needed that to map the stack trace to the code using this file as we can map hex values to function names.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are building from the same source code with the same build options, your output product should be the same (with the possible exception of some timestamps embedded into the code). Any compiler/kernel/library upgrades might break this guarantee.

This is *exactly* what version control (especially tagged snapshots) are for.

Comment: I have it in version control thats why i could revert it back.. But i dont think the same Hex values would be there for functions, as im unable to get the stack trace with the latest lib...